# Flutter alert notification even when the app was closed

Tags: flutter, dart, alarm

I'm developing a application, in that i have come through the situation like I have to show a alert screen with alarm even the app was closed or opened.

[image]

Comment: On which condition you want to show this screen?

Comment: In flutter, showing full screen intent is hard.

If you want to schedule alarm you need to use native code, when the alarm will ring then you can show full screen which should also written natively. (only for android and not possible in ios)

Comment: @Aks like kinda alarm reminder

Comment: okay  so you need to schedule alarms natively